# Error downloading and installing composer

Tags: ssh, php7, shared-hosting, composer

I don't really know where to begin with this. I'm trying to install composer on shared hosting.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://www.ionos.co.uk/digitalguide/websites/web-development/using-php-composer-in-ionos-webhosting-packages/), logged in by SSH and run:

`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | /usr/bin/php7.1-cli`

But I get the following error:

`curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

What's going on?

Thanks